# How to get Files from NextCloud sub-folder and display them externally with unique URL

Tags: file, external, subdirectory, nextcloud

We are in process to integrate NC folders with an external tool. We need to display all files uploaded in a specific folder inside NC from that tool and have them accessible to the user without login via NC.

Using the PROPFIND request call and basic auth, we are able to make request to `‘<DOMAIN_URL/remote.php/dav/files/USERNAME/path/to/folder>’` but the files are not accessible of the user is not logged in to NC and sometimes we get this error when opening the link in a new window:

> ‘{“error”:“Strict Cookie has not been found in request”}’

The shareURL option may end of having a thousands of shared links with multiple users.

We don’t want to download the file then display it from the tool, to avoid redundancy because the user is uploading those files to NC and then he needs to be able to see the files uploaded at any time but from the tool (outside of NC).

Is there any API call or iframe solution (like how NC does the display and the render of the folders and files) to get an explicit URL for each uploaded in the sub folder so the user can open the file from the external tool?

Have tried to use the webdav request call and followed the instructions in the documentation below: `https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/basic.html`

We are able to get the list of all files inside the relevant folder but we cannot display them to the end user because of no public/sharer/unique web URL that can be granted without authentication to NextCloud.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that you are trying to violate the access control NextCloud implements. There is a reason for a session to be required in the web frontend and the same holds true with any other level of access. If you punch a hole into one side of the system - then what is the system for anyway? You could simply use a public file server folder then ... I suggest you explode the options of SSO a bit, that sounds like the best option since you might get around an explicit and manual login that way.